# @Url.RouteUrl is empty in ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following Action on a Controller in ASP.Net MVC 5:

```
[Route("Sprache/{languageName}/Kurs/{courseName}/Text/{value}/Test/{referenzID}", Name = "Textauswahl")]        
public ActionResult SelectedText(string languageName, string courseName, string value, string referenzID)
{

    return View("ShowTextView");
}
```

However, when I try to generate a link via the following it is always empty.

```
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Textauswahl", new { Model.Training.LanguageName, Model.Training.CourseName, Model.Training.Category ,item })">Auswählen</a>
```

[Screenshot from Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scl5r.png)

Here is my RouteConfig:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An empty response from `Url.RouteUrl` indicates that no route matched the parameters you supplied. Passing a route name only narrows the matching criteria to a specific route, but all of the route values must still be present (either passed explicitly or in the current HTTP request) in order for the URL to be generated.

Note that the syntax you are using is incorrect. The values passed to `RouteUrl` must have both keys and values OR the names of the variables passed must match they route keys used in the route.

```
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Textauswahl", new { 
   languageName = Model.Training.LanguageName, 
   courseName = Model.Training.CourseName, 
   value = Model.Training.Category,
   referenzID = item })">Auswählen</a>
```